How do I let OBS automatically record the active monitor?
I've got 7 monitors plugged into my computer and I'd like to do a screen recording of my workflow, but I don't want to record just one monitor or manually switch between monitors or even record all monitors at the same time.
Is there a way I can let OBS Studio automatically switch to the active monitor and record that screen?
So let's say I'm clicking and doing things on Monitor 1, then it needs to record Monitor 1... But once I move my cursor over to Monitor 2, then it automatically needs to record Monitor 2 instead of Monitor 1.
Is this possible in OBS Studio? If yes, then how?
